# Modular programming and compiling a C program in linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, modular

So I have been studying this Modular programming that mainly compiles each file of the program at a time. Say we have FILE.c and OTHER.c that both are in the same program. To compile it, we do this in the prompt

```
$gcc FILE.c OTHER.c -c
```

Using the -c flag to compile it into .o files (FILE.o and OTHER.o) and only when that happens do we translate it (compile) to executable using

```
$gcc FILE.o OTHER.o -o
```

I know I can just do it and skip the middle part but as it shows everywhere, they do it first and then they compile it into executable, which I can't understand at all.

May I know why?

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on a project with several modules, you don't want to recompile all modules if only some of them have been modified. The final linking command is however always needed. Build tools such as *make* is used to keep track of which modules need to be compiled or recompiled.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it in two steps allows to separate more clearly the compiling and linking phases.

- The output of the compiling step is object (.o) files that are machine code but missing the external references of each module (i.e. each c file); for instance file.c might use a function defined in other.c, but the compiler doesn't care about that dependency in that step;
- The input of the linking step is the object files, and its output is the executable. The linking step bind together the object files by filling the blanks (i.e. resolving dependencies between objets files). That's also where you add the libraries to your executable.

Answer (score 1):

This part of another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work/20044489#20044489) responds to your question:

> You might ask why there are separate compilation and linking steps.
>   First, it's probably easier to implement things that way. The compiler
>   does its thing, and the linker does its thing -- by keeping the
>   functions separate, the complexity of the program is reduced. Another
>   (more obvious) advantage is that this allows the creation of large
>   programs without having to redo the compilation step every time a file
>   is changed. Instead, using so called "conditional compilation", it is
>   necessary to compile only those source files that have changed; for
>   the rest, the object files are sufficient input for the linker.
>   Finally, this makes it simple to implement libraries of pre-compiled
>   code: just create object files and link them just like any other
>   object file. (The fact that each file is compiled separately from
>   information contained in other files, incidentally, is called the
>   "separate compilation model".)

It was too long to put in a comment, please give credit to the original answer.